# Thinking Sphinx sql like query in a condition for a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I had these queries, but now I'm trying to use sphinx, and I need to replace them, but I can't find a way to do this:

```
p1 = Product.where "category LIKE ?", "#{WORD}"
p2 = Product.where "category LIKE ?", "#{WORD}.%"
product_list = p1 + p2
```

I'm doing the search over a model named "Product" in "category" field; I need a way to replace "#" and "%" in sphinx. I have a basic idea of how to do that, but this isn't working:

```
Product.search conditions: {category: "('WORD' | 'WORD.*')"}
```

Comment: What does # represent? Know of % as a wildcard in LIKE, but not what # means.

Comment: @barryhunter It means start of the string, I find it also in sphinx [link](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax) with `^WORD$` for exact matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to note.

- If you want to match on prefixes, make sure you have `min_prefix_len` set to 1 or greater (the smaller, the more accurate, but also the slower your searches will be, and the larger your index files will get). Also, you need `enable_star` set to true. Both of these settings belong in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` (there's examples [in the docs](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html)).
- Single quotes have no purpose in Sphinx searches, and will be ignored - but I don't think that's a problem with what you're trying to search with.
- Full stops, however, are treated as word separators by default. You *can* change this with [charset_table](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.1.5.html#conf-charset-table) - but that means all full stops in all fields will be treated as part of words (say, at the end of sentences), so I wouldn't recommend it.

However, if full stops are ignored, then each word in the category field is indexed separately, and so without any extra settings, this should work:

```
Product.search conditions: {category: WORD}
```

Comment: I change the file thinking_sphinx.yml, I also change the charset_table beceuse WORD has dots and it was treated like separator as @pat mentioned and the search is working: `Product.search conditions: {category: "WORD | WORD.*"}`